# onFling not being called in a costum View

Tags: android

I have costume View for, basically, running my game in a different Thread (that being implemented in another class), but although having an onTouchEvent() that's called, I can't make the onFling method get called (tested trough a breakpoint).

**Costum View's class:**

```
public class RenderGameActivity extends SurfaceView implements
    SurfaceHolder.Callback, GestureDetector.OnGestureListener {

private GameThread thread;
private Context context;

private static boolean showPauseMenu;

private GestureDetector gestureScanner;

public RenderGameActivity(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    // adding the callback (this) to the surface holder to intercept events
    getHolder().addCallback(this);

    // create the game loop thread
    thread = new GameThread(getHolder(), this);

    // make the GamePanel focusable so it can handle events
    setFocusable(true);

    gestureScanner = new GestureDetector(context, this);
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(...) {}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    thread.setName("TacticalDefence.game");
    // at this point the surface is created and
    // we can safely start the game loop
    thread.setRunning(true);
    thread.start();
}

public void surfacePaused() {
    synchronized(thread) {
        thread.setRunning(false);
        try {
            thread.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    thread.setRunning(false);

    // tell the thread to shut down and wait for it to finish
    // this is a clean shutdown
    boolean retry = true;
    while (retry) {
        try {
            thread.join();
            retry = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // try again shutting down the thread
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    Game.onTouchEvent(event);
    return gestureScanner.onTouchEvent(event);
}

public void render(Canvas canvas) {
    Game.onDraw(context, canvas);
    // display fps
    if(IsInDebug.isInDebugMode(context)) displayFps(canvas, avgFps);
}

/**
 * This is the game update method. It iterates through all the objects
 * and calls their update method if they have one or calls specific
 * engine's update method.
 */
public void update() { Game.onUpdate();}

/*...*/

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    return Game.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
}
}
```

Sorry if it's too much code, but I feel that I have to post it because I don't which part will be useful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may not be the best way to solve the problem, but I could not find other way...
I used this code to "remake" the onFling() method:

```
private static float [] e1;
private static float start;


@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    boolean d = true;
    if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        MotionEvent e2 = event;
        float velocityX = Math.abs((e1 [0] - e2.getX()) / start);
        float velocityY = Math.abs((e1 [0] - e2.getY()) / start);
        onFling(e1, event, velocityX, velocityY);
    } else if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        e1 = new float[] {event.getX(), event.getY()};
        start = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
    }
    Game.onTouchEvent(event);
    return true;
}

public static boolean onFling(float[] e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    return Game.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
}
```

Related: [MotionEvent changes from ACTION_UP to ACTION_DOWN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28286669/motionevent-changes-from-action-up-to-action-down)