# MotionEvent changes from ACTION_UP to ACTION_DOWN

Tags: android

In this code:

```
private static MotionEvent e1;
private static float start;

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        MotionEvent e2 = event;
        float velocityX = Math.abs((e1.getX() - e2.getX()) / start);
        float velocityY = Math.abs((e1.getY() - e2.getY()) / start);
        onFling(e1, event, velocityX, velocityY);//BREAKPOINT 2
    } else if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        e1 = event;
        start = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;//BREAKPOINT 1
    }
    return Game.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

If I put a break point on the "BREAKPOINT 1" line, I get that: `e1.getActionMasked()` equals `ACTION_DOWN`. But when it stops in "BREAKPOINT 2" I get that `e1` equals `event`. Also if I add `&& event != e1` to the first "if" the code in it is skipped.Why is this happening?

If you want to know why I am using this approach to replace `onFling()` see this: [onFling not being called in a costum View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28267515/onfling-to-being-called-in-a-costum-view)

Comment: what? am I the only one who doesn't understand what's been asked?

Comment: @Pavel Dudka, Sorry, do you understand it now? I am trying to imitate the work of  `onFling()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android does some memory optimization here. Since touch events happen really a lot during the gesture - instead of creating `MotionEvent` instance every time `onTouchEvent` happens, Android reuses previous `MotionEvent` instance, so you don't pollute your heap memory.

Since you store the reference to `MotionEvent` (ACTION_DOWN) in your case - your `ev1` is getting updated every time `onTouchEvent` is called. That's why when `ACTION_UP` happens - your `ev1` equals to the latest motion event. It is the same instance as it used to be during `ACTION_DOWN`.

Instead of storing `MotionEvent` instance - you need to store `x` and `y` coordinates during `ACTION_DOWN`