# Kotlin runnable in a thread is using a different value than the one passed

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to run a thread on Android, with the following code:

```
    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        Log.d("CustomImage", " touched : ${event!!.x}, ${event.y}")
        Thread(Runnable {
            if(threadRunning) {
                return@Runnable
            }
            threadRunning = true
            consumeTouchEvent(event)
        }).start()


        return super.onTouchEvent(event)
    }

    private fun consumeTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent) {
        Log.d("CustomImage", " consumeTouchEvent x,y : ${event.x}, ${event.y}")
        Thread.sleep(1000)   //long running task
        threadRunning = false
    }
```

Here's the corresponding log after I touch the view:

```
01-03 00:17:05.654 8122-8122/me.exp D/CustomImage:  touched : 960.0, 299.0
01-03 00:17:05.656 8122-8250/me.exp D/CustomImage:  consumeTouchEvent x,y : 960.0, 509.0
```

As evident, the 'Y' value for touch event is 299.0, but in consume method, it gets updated to 509.

One possible explanation I could think was that multiple touch events are fired when I touch the screen and what's logged in `consumeTouchEvent()` is a later value - but in that case, `onTouchEvent()` should be logging all the touch values.

This problem goes away if I run `consumeTouchEvent()` without spawning a new thread.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28287492/1524450  `event` should remain unchanged until you return from `onTouchEvent`, but after that all bets are off. Make a copy of the event if you need those values later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Android framework may reuse instances of `MotionEvent` to avoid heap pollution and excessive garbage collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28286669/motionevent-changes-from-action-up-to-action-down). The [`recycle`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) method in particular is used to mark the `event` as immediately available for reuse:

> Recycle the MotionEvent, to be re-used by a later caller. After calling this function you must not ever touch the event again.

Before your `Runnable` you've created has a chance to execute the `onTouchEvent` has already returned and thus Android has reused the `MotionEvent` instance.

You can [`obtain`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#obtain(android.view.MotionEvent)) your own copy for processing like so:

```
val myEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(event)
// do some work
myEvent.recycle()
```

Your example would then look like:

```
val myEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(event)
thread {
    if(threadRunning) {
        return@Runnable
    }
    threadRunning = true
    consumeTouchEvent(myEvent)
    myEvent.recycle()
}
return super.onTouchEvent(event)
```